# Chrome crashes when I upload a high resolution image

Tags: javascript, jquery, out-of-memory

My script takes a zip file and then unzips it and creates video frames from images. It works for lower resolution but when I upload a zip file in which the image have higher resolutions like 4000 x 4000. The chrome tab hangs and then crashes.
The code that unzip the file is

```
function processZip(file) { 
$('.accordion').hide();
JSZip.loadAsync(file).then((zip, i = 0) => {
    length = Object.keys(zip.files).length
    var frames = new Array;
    $('.uk-container').append(`<p class="uk-text-right progress-frames">0/${length} frames processed | 0% | ETA: ${Math.round((settings.timeout/1000 * length)/renderers.count)} seconds</p><progress class="uk-progress" value="0" max="${length}"></progress>`);
    zip.forEach((relativePath, zipEntry) => {
        zipEntry.async('base64').then(out => {
            i++;
            // var blob = new Blob([out], {
            //     'type': 'image/png'
            // }); 

            frames.push({
                image: out,
                path: relativePath
            });
            if (i == length) {
                processImages(frames);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

}

And the code for image Processing is

```
function processImages(frames) {
var chunkSize = Math.ceil(length/renderers.count);
var cutframes = frames.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => { 
    const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/chunkSize)
    if(!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
        resultArray[chunkIndex] = []
    }
    resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)
    return resultArray
}, [])
for (const key in cutframes) {
    console.log('key', key)
    if (cutframes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = cutframes[key];
        bc.postMessage({
            type: 'renderOrder',
            frames: element,
            settings: settings,
            renderer: renderers.instances[key]
        })
    }
}
```

}
I think the problem is related to memory but I couldn't find the main error which takes that much memory.
Can anyone help me with this issue. if someone can help I will contact him personally and take guidance from that person.

Comment: welcome! i would reach out to chrome support.

Comment: Probably not.  Google Chrome Help: https://support.google.com/chrome/